# Prisma Appsync generator not working when run the npm run deploy command

Tags: typescript, lambda, graphql, prisma, vercel

I'm using local mode successfully, but trying to deploy, I can't complete the command npm run deploy.

cdk synth never complete the step: RUN npm install --global yarn@1.22.5
[Step by step](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Lw0rF.png)

I'm test with nodejs versions 16 & 18
    "aws-cdk": "2.99.1",
    "aws-cdk-lib": "2.99.1"

I'm testing default tutorial from https://prisma-appsync.vercel.app/quick-start/getting-started.html

Anyone can help me?

I want to resolve deploy on aws with appsync-prisma generator